# "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" while overriding EventSource

Tags: javascript

**Playground link**: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse

**Problem:**
I am trying to override EventSource in such a way that there will be a console.log whenever onmessage triggers.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if (typeof EventSource !== "undefined") {

  const original = EventSource;

  // part of chrome extension
  window.EventSource = function EventSource(url) {
    const ori = new original(url);

    Object.getPrototypeOf(ori).onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log(event); // log on every message
      ori.onmessage(event);
    };

    return ori;
  };
  
  
  
  // actual source code
  var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
  source.onmessage = function (event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
  };
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But I am getting this error:

**Error:**

> VM461:10 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
> at new EventSource (:10:42)
> at :21:16
> at submitTryit (tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse:853:17)
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse:755:133)
> EventSource @ VM461:10
> (anonymous) @ VM461:21
> submitTryit @ tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse:853
> onclick @ tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse:755
> uic.js?v=1.0.5:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: adngin is not defined
> at uic_r_p (uic.js?v=1.0.5:1:54492)
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse:755:148)
> uic_r_p @ uic.js?v=1.0.5:1
> onclick @ tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse:755

Comment: Do you really just want to log every event? If you actually want to intercept it, and control whether the `source.onmessage` handler is called (or with that value), I can adjust my answer to also show that

Answer (score 2):

`EventSource.prototype.onmessage` is a setter that will try to attach the given value as a listener for the `message` event on the current instance (i.e. the one on which you tried to assign the `.onmessage = …`, i.o.w. the *receiver* of the *[[Set]]* invocation). The problem is that when you run

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(ori).onmessage = …
```

you are not doing this on an actual `EventSource` instance, but rather on its prototype object (`EventSource.prototype`), which causes the setter to the "*TypeError: Illegal invocation*".

To fix this, just add your extra handler using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), so that it doesn't conflict with the `source.onmessage = …` assignment later.

```
const original = window.EventSource;
window.EventSource = function EventSource(url) {
    const instance = new original(url);
    instance.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        console.log(event); // log on every message
    });
    return instance;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this error is occurring because you're trying to create a new instance of EventSource without the proper context. When you override EventSource, you need to make sure that the new instance (ori in your case) is properly set up to handle the original EventSource functionality.

Here's a modified version of your code that should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if (typeof EventSource !== "undefined") {
  const original = EventSource;

  window.EventSource = function CustomEventSource(url) {
    const ori = new original(url);

    ori.onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log(event); // log on every message
      // You might want to handle the event here or trigger your custom logic
      // For now, I'm just passing it to the original onmessage handler
      if (ori.onmessage) {
        ori.onmessage(event);
      }
    };

    return ori;
  };

  var source = new window.EventSource("demo_sse.php");
  source.onmessage = function (event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
  };
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

PS: Kindly regard this line:
`var source = new window.EventSource("demo_sse.php");`
you should ensure this `demo_sse.php` in your local.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if (typeof EventSource !== "undefined") {

  const original = EventSource;

  // part of chrome extension
  window.EventSource = function EventSource(url) {
    const ori = new original(url);

    Object.getPrototypeOf(ori).onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log(event); // log on every message
      ori.onmessage(event);
    };

    return ori;
  };
  
  // actual source code
  var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
  source.onmessage = function (event) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
  };
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The potential issue in this code is that the EventSource is trying to connect to a server-sent events (aka. SSE) source at "demo_sse.php," but the actual server-sent events source code for handling the updates is not provided. Make sure that the "demo_sse.php" file contains the necessary code to send server updates using SSE.